# Why does += behave unexpectedly on lists?

Tags: python, augmented-assignment

The `+=` operator in python seems to be operating unexpectedly on lists.  Can anyone tell me what is going on here?

```
class foo:  
     bar = []
     def __init__(self,x):
         self.bar += [x]


class foo2:
     bar = []
     def __init__(self,x):
          self.bar = self.bar + [x]

f = foo(1)
g = foo(2)
print f.bar
print g.bar 

f.bar += [3]
print f.bar
print g.bar

f.bar = f.bar + [4]
print f.bar
print g.bar

f = foo2(1)
g = foo2(2)
print f.bar 
print g.bar
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[1, 2]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3]
[1]
[2]
```

`foo += bar` seems to affect every instance of the class, whereas `foo = foo + bar` seems to behave in the way I would expect things to behave.

The `+=` operator is called a "compound assignment operator".

Comment: see the difference between 'extend' and 'append' on list too

Comment: I don't think this shows something wrong with Python. Most languages wouldn't even allow you to use the `+` operator on arrays. I think it makes perfect sense in this case that `+=` would append.

Comment: It's is called 'augmented assignment', officially.

Comment: btw, using `my_list += [x]` is terrible style.  Please don't do this

Answer (score 199):

The general answer is that `+=` tries to call the `__iadd__` special method, and if that isn't available it tries to use `__add__` instead. So the issue is with the difference between these special methods.

The `__iadd__` special method is for an in-place addition, that is it mutates the object that it acts on. The `__add__` special method returns a new object and is also used for the standard `+` operator.

So when the `+=` operator is used on an object which has an `__iadd__` defined the object is modified in place. Otherwise it will instead try to use the plain `__add__` and return a new object.

That is why for mutable types like lists `+=` changes the object's value, whereas for immutable types like tuples, strings and integers a new object is returned instead (`a += b` becomes equivalent to `a = a + b`).

For types that support both `__iadd__` and `__add__` you therefore have to be careful which one you use. `a += b` will call `__iadd__` and mutate `a`, whereas `a = a + b` will create a new object and assign it to `a`. They are not the same operation!

```
>>> a1 = a2 = [1, 2]
>>> b1 = b2 = [1, 2]
>>> a1 += [3]          # Uses __iadd__, modifies a1 in-place
>>> b1 = b1 + [3]      # Uses __add__, creates new list, assigns it to b1
>>> a2
[1, 2, 3]              # a1 and a2 are still the same list
>>> b2
[1, 2]                 # whereas only b1 was changed
```

For immutable types (where you don't have an `__iadd__`) `a += b` and `a = a + b` are equivalent. This is what lets you use `+=` on immutable types, which might seem a strange design decision until you consider that otherwise you couldn't use `+=` on immutable types like numbers!

Comment: There is also `__radd__` method that might be called sometimes (it is relevant for expressions that involve subclasses mostly).

Comment: In perspective: += is useful if memory and speed are important

Comment: Knowing that `+=` actually *extends* a list, this explains why `x = []; x = x + {}` gives a `TypeError` while `x = []; x += {}` just returns `[]`.

Comment: This answer is missing the (very important) fact that `bar` is a class variable. That, together with this answer, actually explain the observed behaviour. @AndiDog answer is better in that sense.

Answer (score 110):

For the general case, see [Scott Griffith's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2347423/1709587). When dealing with lists like you are, though, the `+=` operator is a shorthand for `someListObject.extend(iterableObject)`. See the [documentation of extend()](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html).

The `extend` function will append all elements of the parameter to the list.

When doing `foo += something` you're modifying the list `foo` in place, thus you don't change the reference that the name `foo` points to, but you're changing the list object directly. With `foo = foo + something`, you're actually creating a *new* list.

This example code will explain it:

```
>>> l = []
>>> id(l)
13043192
>>> l += [3]
>>> id(l)
13043192
>>> l = l + [3]
>>> id(l)
13059216
```

Note how the reference changes when you reassign the new list to `l`.

As `bar` is a class variable instead of an instance variable, modifying in place will affect all instances of that class. But when redefining `self.bar`, the instance will have a separate instance variable `self.bar` without affecting the other class instances.

Comment: This is not always true : a = 1; a += 1; is valid Python, but ints don't have any "extend()" methods. You can't generalize this.

Comment: Done some testings, Scott Griffiths got it right, so -1 for you.

Comment: @e-statis: The OP was clearly speaking about lists, and I clearly stated that I'm talking about lists, too. I'm not generalizing anything.

Comment: Removed the -1, the answer is good enought. I still think Griffiths' answer is better though.

Comment: At first it feels weird to think that `a += b` is different from `a = a + b` for two lists `a` and `b`. But it makes sense; `extend` would more often be the intended thing to do with lists rather than create a new copy of the entire list which will have higher time complexity. If developers need to be careful that they do not modify the original lists in place, then tuples are a better option being immutable objects. `+=` with tuples cannot modify the original tuple.

Answer (score 22):

The problem here is, `bar` is defined as a class attribute, not an instance variable.

In `foo`, the class attribute is modified in the `init` method, that's why all instances are affected.

In `foo2`, an instance variable is defined using the (empty) class attribute, and every instance gets its own `bar`.

The "correct" implementation would be:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.bar = [x]
```

Of course, class attributes are completely legal. In fact, you can access and modify them without creating an instance of the class like this:

```
class foo:
    bar = []

foo.bar = [x]
```

Answer (score 11):

There are two things involved here:

```
1. class attributes and instance attributes
2. difference between the operators + and += for lists
```

`+` operator calls the `__add__` method on a list. It takes all the elements from its operands and makes a new list containing those elements maintaining their order.

`+=` operator calls `__iadd__` method on the list. It takes an iterable and appends all the elements of the iterable to the list in place. It does not create a new list object.

In class `foo` the statement  `self.bar += [x]` is not an assignment statement but actually translates to

```
self.bar.__iadd__([x])  # modifies the class attribute
```

which modifies the list in place and acts like the list method `extend`.

In class `foo2`, on the contrary, the assignment statement in the `init` method

```
self.bar = self.bar + [x]
```

can be deconstructed as:
The instance has no attribute `bar` (there is a class attribute of the same name, though) so it accesses the class attribute `bar` and creates a new list by appending `x` to it. The statement translates to:

```
self.bar = self.bar.__add__([x]) # bar on the lhs is the class attribute
```

Then it creates an instance attribute `bar` and assigns the newly created list to it. Note that `bar` on the rhs of the assignment is different from the `bar` on the lhs.

For instances of class `foo`, `bar` is a class attribute and not instance attribute. Hence any change to the class attribute `bar` will be reflected for all instances.

On the contrary, each instance of the class `foo2` has its own instance attribute `bar` which is different from the class attribute of the same name `bar`.

```
f = foo2(4)
print f.bar # accessing the instance attribute. prints [4]  
print f.__class__.bar # accessing the class attribute. prints []
```

Hope this clears things.

Answer (score 7):

Although much time has passed and many correct things were said, there is no answer which bundles both effects.

You have 2 effects:

1. a "special", maybe unnoticed behaviour of lists with `+=` (as stated by [Scott Griffiths](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2347423/296974))
2. the fact that class attributes as well as instance attributes are involved (as stated by [Can Berk Büder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2347278/296974))

In class `foo`, the `__init__` method modifies the class attribute. It is because `self.bar += [x]` translates to `self.bar = self.bar.__iadd__([x])`. `__iadd__()` is for inplace modification, so it modifies the list and returns a reference to it.

Note that the instance dict is modified although this would normally not be necessary as the class dict already contains the same assignment. So this detail goes almost unnoticed - except if you do a `foo.bar = []` afterwards. Here the instances's `bar` stays the same thanks to the said fact.

In class `foo2`, however, the class's `bar` is used, but not touched. Instead, a `[x]` is added to it, forming a new object, as `self.bar.__add__([x])` is called here, which doesn't modify the object. The result is put into the instance dict then, giving the instance the new list as a dict, while the class's attribute stays modified.

The distinction between `... = ... + ...` and `... += ...` affects as well the assignments afterwards:

```
f = foo(1) # adds 1 to the class's bar and assigns f.bar to this as well.
g = foo(2) # adds 2 to the class's bar and assigns g.bar to this as well.
# Here, foo.bar, f.bar and g.bar refer to the same object.
print f.bar # [1, 2]
print g.bar # [1, 2]

f.bar += [3] # adds 3 to this object
print f.bar # As these still refer to the same object,
print g.bar # the output is the same.

f.bar = f.bar + [4] # Construct a new list with the values of the old ones, 4 appended.
print f.bar # Print the new one
print g.bar # Print the old one.

f = foo2(1) # Here a new list is created on every call.
g = foo2(2)
print f.bar # So these all obly have one element.
print g.bar
```

You can verify the identity of the objects with `print id(foo), id(f), id(g)` (don't forget the additional `()`s if you are on Python3).

BTW: The `+=` operator is called "augmented assignment" and generally is intended to do inplace modifications as far as possible.

Answer (score 6):

The other answers would seem to pretty much have it covered, though it seems worth quoting and referring to the [Augmented Assignments PEP 203](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0203/):

> They *[the augmented assignment operators]* implement the same operator
>   as their normal binary form, except that the operation is done
>   `in-place' when the left-hand side object supports it, and that the
>   left-hand side is only evaluated once.

...

> The idea behind augmented
>   assignment in Python is that it isn't just an easier way to write the
>   common practice of storing the result of a binary operation in its
>   left-hand operand, but also a way for the left-hand operand in
>   question to know that it should operate `on itself', rather than
>   creating a modified copy of itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> elements=[[1],[2],[3]]
>>> subset=[]
>>> subset+=elements[0:1]
>>> subset
[[1]]
>>> elements
[[1], [2], [3]]
>>> subset[0][0]='change'
>>> elements
[['change'], [2], [3]]

>>> a=[1,2,3,4]
>>> b=a
>>> a+=[5]
>>> a,b
([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> a=[1,2,3,4]
>>> b=a
>>> a=a+[5]
>>> a,b
([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Answer (score 1):

````
>>> a = 89
>>> id(a)
4434330504
>>> a = 89 + 1
>>> print(a)
90
>>> id(a)
4430689552  # this is different from before!

>>> test = [1, 2, 3]
>>> id(test)
48638344L
>>> test2 = test
>>> id(test)
48638344L
>>> test2 += [4]
>>> id(test)
48638344L
>>> print(test, test2)  # [1, 2, 3, 4] [1, 2, 3, 4]```
([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> id(test2)
48638344L # ID is different here
````

We see that when we attempt to modify an immutable object (integer in this case), Python simply gives us a different object instead. On the other hand, we are able to make changes to an mutable object (a list) and have it remain the same object throughout.

ref : https://medium.com/@tyastropheus/tricky-python-i-memory-management-for-mutable-immutable-objects-21507d1e5b95

Also refer below url to understand the shallowcopy and deepcopy

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/copy-python-deep-copy-shallow-copy/

Comment: # ID is same for Lists