# Concat list and string in Python

Tags: python, string, list, concatenation

I am a bit do not understand the principle of the addition of lists and strings in Python.

For example, we have a list:

`students = ['Ivan', 'Michael', 'Olga']`

The result of the expression:

`students += 'John'`

will be:

`['Ivan', 'Michael', 'Olga', 'J', 'o', 'h', 'n']`

And in this case, string 'John' will be processed as a list and every symbol will be added to list `students`.

But why the processing of expression:

`students = students + 'John'`

occurs otherwise?
In this case, we just get an error.

I always thought that expressions `a += b` and `a = a + b` are equivalent. 
But why here in one case the string is expanded to the list, and in the other case this does not happen and we get an error?

Comment: In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951792/python-a-b-not-the-same-as-a-a-b) topic you can see why.

Comment: @mxsin, you can have a look at this https://hygull.github.io/codes/python2.7/stackoverflow/Q1.html. Here I have taken your problem as input and got the desired output.

Answer (score 2):

This is expression `a += b` or `a = a + b` will not help you with list.

If you want to add one element to list then you can try.

```
students = ['Ivan', 'Michael', 'Olga']
students.append('John')
```

If you want to join to list. Then you can do.

```
students = ['Ivan', 'Michael', 'Olga']
student = ['John']
students = students + student
```

Or

```
 students.extend(student) #This list concatenation method is bit faster.
```

If you want to dig deeper. You can refer to this [article here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347265/why-does-behave-unexpectedly-on-lists)