# What does the += signify in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

For example, when adding lists together:

```py
list = [1,2,3,4,5]

list_sum = 0
for x in list:
   list_sum += x
```

Comment: Most symbols are now indexed in the Symbols page https://docs.python.org/3/genindex-Symbols.html

Answer (score 2):

`list_sum += x` means add the contents of `list_sum` variable with the contents of variable `x` and again store the result to `list_sum` variable.

Code explanation:

```
list_sum = 0     # At first, 0 is assigned to the `list_sum` variable .
for x in list:   # iterating over the contents which are present inside the variable `list`
list_sum += x    # list_sum = 0+1 . After the first iteration, value 1 is stored to list_sum variable. Likewise it sums up the values present in  the list and then assign it back to list_sum variable. Atlast `list_sum` contains the sum of all the values present inside the given list.
```

Answer (score 1):

It's [shorthand](http://pymbook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/operatorsexpressions.html) for `list_sum = list_sum + x`

`for x in list:` will loop once through every element in `list`, assigning the value to a temporary variable `x`

Check out these duplicates:

[Duplicate 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841436/what-exactly-does-do-in-python)and not exactly a duplicate but [another example of how it works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347265/why-does-behave-unexpectedly-on-lists)

Comment: "It adds an element" is kind of confusing.  You should change how you word this.

Comment: Fair enough, reworded it.

Comment: It's not exactly the same as `list_sum = list_sum + x`. That implies that a new object is created and then assigned to the name `list_sum`. This is true for immutable objects, but for mutable objects `+=` is an in-place operator and modifies the existing object. The main difference being that other references will also se the change. eg. `x = []; y = x; y += [1]; assert x == y`, whereas `x = 0; y = x; y += 1; assert x != y`.

Answer (score -1):

It is shortened operation used in any language `list_sum += x  =>  list_sum = list_sum + x`
There can also be "-=", "*=" and "/=" respectively.