# Why cant i get the total from a While true loop

Tags: python

I cant seem to get the total from my while true loop. I am trying to write a code . That will get the total value for all the seats a waiter enters. But I keep getting the total like this    Total:$ q     I had set q to break if the user input it for a seats. Can you help me please.  Here is my syntax.

```
while True:                                           
    seats = raw_input("Enter the value of the seat [q to quit]:")
    if seats  ==  'q':
       break
    print "Total: $", seats
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
total = 0
while True:
    seats = raw_input("Enter the value of the seat [q to quit]:")
    if seats == 'q':
        break
    total += int(seats)
print "Total: $", str(total)
```

If you want it to show the total after each loop just push the print statement inside the loop.

Comment: Hello Wright thanks for replying to my question. Well I tried your method but when i try to enter q to quit if gives me an error message. Does it matter that im using python 2.7.6

Comment: Wow it worked Wright I appreciate you and your intellect. I just went ahead and changed the   int(seats)   to    float(seats)   so it can work for any  input that has a decimal in it. Thanks a lot Wright : )

Comment: Ah that's great news :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to sum variable seats with your input value, not reassigning value.
You were wrong in choosing operator, you need to use `+=`, not `=`.

Replace your code with this:

```
 while True:
     input = raw_input("Enter the value of the seat [q to quit]:")
     if input  ==  'q':
         break
     seats += input
 print "Total: $", seats
```

After that, read this question and answers:
[What exactly does += do in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841436/what-exactly-does-do-in-python)

Comment: I appreciate you anwsering Syncro but its not working now it wont run the program im using python 2.7.6 does that matter

Comment: I appreciate it Syncro but Wright figured it out I wasn't setting a variable named total so that i can keep the total amount in a variable. And it can be printed out as total