# Python: How do I add variables with integer values together?

Tags: python

I'm new to Python. How do I add variables with integer values together?

```
balance = 1000
deposit = 50
balance + deposit
print "Balance: " + str(balance)
```

I want balance and deposit to add together to it 1050, but I'm just getting 1000. I know I'm clearly not formatting it (balance + deposit) correctly, but I can't figure out the right way to format it.

Thanks.

Comment: `balance += deposit`

Comment: Since no one else has said this yet, I will: you would probably benefit hugely from an introduction-to-Python tutorial (eg. [this one](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/introduction) or [that one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rkx5_MRAV3A)). StackOverflow doesn't teach you the basics of programming, it just gives specific answers to specific questions.

Answer (score 12):

Doing this:

```
balance + deposit
```

Does the addition and returns the result (1050). However, that result isn't stored anywhere. You need to assign it to a variable:

```
total = balance + deposit
```

Or, if you want to increment `balance` instead of using a new variable, you can use the [`+=` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841436/what-exactly-does-do-in-python):

```
balance += deposit
```

This is equivalent to doing:

```
balance = balance + deposit
```

Comment: Or assign it back to `balance`: `balance = balance + deposit` or `balance += deposit`

Comment: Note that a += b is not always equivalent to a = a + b, they are equivalent for numbers, strings and tuples but not for lists.

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign the sum to a variable before printing.

```
balance = 1000
deposit = 50
total = balance + deposit
print "Balance: " + str(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the assignment operator:
balance = balance + deposit
OR
balance += deposit