# How do I allow my program to add the sum of even numbers between two numbers entered by the user? USING PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.3

I have to include a function in my code and so I wrote the code below but I do not know how to add all the even numbers between the two numbers entered by the user. It prints the even numbers only, it does not add them.

```
def sum_of_two_no(num1, num2):
    for evenno in range(num1, num2 + 1):
        if evenno % 2 == 0:
            print (evenno)
num1 = 0
num2 = 0

num1 = int(input("Enter first number: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter second number number: "))

sum_of_two_no(num1, num2)
```

---

For example: If the user entered 1 for the first number and 10 for the second number, the program displays the even numbers between 1 and 10, but it does not add them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: How do I add variables with integer values together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45744364/python-how-do-i-add-variables-with-integer-values-together)

Answer (score 1):

```
def sum_of_two_no(num1, num2):
    sum=0
    for evenno in range(num1, num2 + 1):
        if evenno % 2 == 0:
            sum+=evenno 
    return sum
```

I assume you are in initial phase of learning. To get the sum you have to actually do something to store the sum. Just take a variable and sum up all those even numbers in it and then just simply return it.

Answer (score 1):

Try the code

```
def sum_of_two_no(num1, num2):
    sum=0
    for i in range(num1,num2+1):
        if i%2==0:
            sum+=i
    return sum

print(sum_of_two_no(4,7))
```

The problem with your code was that it wasnt storing the value of even numbers it was only printing it

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

The sum of all even numbers from 1 to n is given by the n:th [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number): `n(n+1)/2`. Simularily, the sum of 2, 4, ..., 2n is `n(n+1)`. Hence we can compute this in O(1) by

```
def sum_of_two_no(num1, num2):
    # fix boundaries
    num1 = num1 // 2 - 1   # We subtract sum of 2, 4, ..., num1 - 2
    num2 = num2 // 2       # We add sum of 2, 4, ..., num2

    # Compute upper sum - lower sum
    return num2 * (num2 + 1) - num1 * (num1 + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just loop through the evens without checking:

```
def sum_of_two_no(num1, num2):
    mysum = 0
    for evenno in range(start=num1+num1%2, stop=num2+1, step=2):
        mysum += evenno
    return mysum
```

The num1%2 insures we start at the closest even number.

Or you can one-line it in a pythonic way:

```
evensum = sum([evenno for evenno in range(start=num1+num1%2, stop=num2+1, step=2)])
```