# Is there syntactic sugar for rewriting pandas column values?

Tags: python, pandas

For example I lets say I have the dataframe **df** with column **A** containing ints.

If I wanted to change all the values in **A** so that they all had 1 added to them I would write something like this:

```
df["A"] = df["A"] + 1
```

Is there a way to write this so I don't have to write df["A"] twice?

Comment: Yes, `df["A"] += 1`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841436/what-exactly-does-do-in-python

Comment: Or even df.A for short

Comment: also `df.A.add(1)` is worth mentioned, although `df.A += 1` is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>Most of these solutions have been mentioned in comments, so I'm just fleshing them out as answers here.</sub>

---

**Option 1**
Direct assignment. The most idiomatic approach.

```
df['A'] += 1
```

Alternatively, you could use the *dot notation* for accessing columns:

```
df.A += 1
```

This, however, will not work for columns that have spaces in them, or begin with digits.

---

**Option 2**
Using *`df.assign`* <sub>(better if you want a copy, rather than inplace assignment)</sub>

```
df = df.assign(A=df['A'] + 1)
```

You can also use this in conjunction with *`df.add`* as pointed out:

```
df = df.assign(A=df['A'].add(1))
```