# python list of char append with +

Tags: python

I found something puzzled me in Python earlier on, let's say I got a list of chars `l = ['a','b']`

when I do `l + 'c'` it gives me error of 'can only concatenate list (not "str") to list'. However `l += 'c'` is fine which gives me `l = ['a', 'b', 'c']`. Does anyone know why that is? (I am on Python 3.7.0)

Comment: good read ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841436/what-exactly-does-do-in-python

Comment: I disagree with the dup. This question is specifically about `+` vs `+=` on the list type. A question about the general behavior of the `+` and `+=` desugaring is not the same thing.

Comment: Does the duplicate really answer why _in this special case_ `list + str` does not work, but `list += str` is interpreted as `list += list(str)`?

Comment: `+=` means "extend this list with the given items" (the items in this case being the sequence of characters in the string). `+` means "concatenate these two lists into a new list".

Answer (score 2):

With `l + 'c'`, you are trying to merge a string and a list. But with `l += 'c'`, you’re essentially doing the same as `l.extend('c')`.

Comment: That's not entirely correct. `l += 'c'` will `extend`, not `append` to the list.

Comment: ...which is why `l += 'cd'` will give you `l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`.

Comment: To be perfectly clear, `+=` works for *any* iterable, and strings are iterable. It's not a special case for strings; it's just that the natural behavior of `+=` (and `extend`, as already pointed out) works here, whereas `+` is specialized for lists. Good answer though!

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t know about the extend part