# How to create an array from a given array of ranges

Tags: python, arrays, range

I have this code:

```
    pg=[(10, 19), (30, 32), (37, 38), (50, 59), (63, 64),
    (69, 69), (120, 121), (124, 129), (130, 139), (160, 161),
    (164, 169), (180, 182), (185, 185), (189, 189), (190, 192),
    (194, 194), (196, 199), (260, 269), (270, 279), (300, 309),
    (330, 339), (358, 359), (360, 369)]
```

Those are given ranges, for example, `pg[0]` should be 10, `pg[1]` be 11, `pg[2]` be 12. and so on for the rest of the ranges. So I want the final array to be like this:

```
    pg=[10, 11, 12, 13 ....19, 30, 31,....,32,37, 38,50,51,....,59,63.. and so on]
```

How can I do this in python? Is it possible to do it without hard coding every range of elements in a new array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the following might work

```
pg = [(10, 19), (30, 32), (37, 38), (50, 59), (63, 64),
    (69, 69), (120, 121), (124, 129), (130, 139), (160, 161),
    (164, 169), (180, 182), (185, 185), (189, 189), (190, 192),
    (194, 194), (196, 199), (260, 269), (270, 279), (300, 309),
    (330, 339), (358, 359), (360, 369)]
arr = []
for val in pg:
    arr += list(range(val[0], val[1] + 1))
print(arr)
```

Comment: why when I only wrtie ar = list(range(val[0],val[1])), it won't work. I mean it gives me an error

Comment: it should be `arr += list(range(val[0], val[1] + 1))`, did you notice `+=`

Comment: yes I did, I'm asking about the above code, I'm just asking if I write the following without the for loop:
arr = list(range(pg[0], pg[1] + 1))
because I want to understand how this is working. if I write this it gives an error. 
notice I put pg instead of val

Comment: Kindly go through the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4841436/2825570), for better understanding.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
l = []
for r in pg:
    l.extend(range(r[0], r[1]+1))
```

Comment: thanks for bringing that to my attention. I have edited my code.

Answer (score 2):

This is one approach using a list comprehension and `itertools.chain`(to flatten the list)

**Ex:**

```
from itertools import chain
pg=[(10, 19), (30, 32), (37, 38), (50, 59), (63, 64),
    (69, 69), (120, 121), (124, 129), (130, 139), (160, 161),
    (164, 169), (180, 182), (185, 185), (189, 189), (190, 192),
    (194, 194), (196, 199), (260, 269), (270, 279), (300, 309),
    (330, 339), (358, 359), (360, 369)]

result = list(chain.from_iterable([range(*i) for i in pg]))
print(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

A one-linear

```
 sum([list(range(x1, x2+1)) for x1, x2 in pg], [])
```

Comment: great but generator expression must be parenthesized

Comment: After running this wizardry, I still don't understand it.

Comment: @BenoîtPilatte: the comprehension makes a list of lists (each list is a `range`). The `sum` just applies the `+` operator between the lists, starting from an empty list

Answer (score 1):

One more example using list comprehension

```
a = [(10, 19), (30, 35)]
b = [j for i in a for j in range(i[0], i[1]+1)]
print(b) 

#output
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]
```

Answer (score 0):

with help of sum function also we can achieve this.

```
pg=[(10, 19), (30, 32), (37, 38), (50, 59), (63, 64),
    (69, 69), (120, 121), (124, 129), (130, 139), (160, 161),
    (164, 169), (180, 182), (185, 185), (189, 189), (190, 192),
    (194, 194), (196, 199), (260, 269), (270, 279), (300, 309),
    (330, 339), (358, 359), (360, 369)]      

print (list(sum(pg,())))

#output:[10, 19, 30, 32, 37, 38, 50, 59, 63, 64, 69, 69, 120, 121, 124, 129, 130, 139, 
#160, 161, 164, 169, 180, 182, 185, 185, 189, 189, 190, 192, 194, 194, 196, 199, 260, 
#269, 270, 279, 300, 309, 330, 339, 358, 359, 360, 369]
```