# The += operator messes up list assignment in class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The `+=` operator does an odd list assignment.

This is for a home project. I'm running on Ubuntu and using Python 3.x.

When using `+=` I get this unexpected behaviour:

```py
class foo:
    def __init__(self, arg=[]):
        self.arg = arg

x = foo()
for _ in range(100):
    x.arg += [foo()]

x.arg == foo().arg
# True
```

And when I don't:

```py
class foo:
    def __init__(self, arg=[]):
        self.arg = arg

x = foo()
for _ in range(100):
    x.arg = x.arg + [foo()]

x.arg == foo().arg
# False
```

I expect `x.arg == foo().arg`, to return `False` and NOT `True` in the first case.

## Edit:

This might be a duplicate of [“Least Astonishment” and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument), but why is the `x.arg += [foo()]` behaviour different from `x.arg = x.arg + [foo()]`?

Comment: Probably part of the answer, but why is the behaviour using `+=` different?

Comment: I think this is *actually* rather a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347265/why-does-behave-unexpectedly-on-lists?noredirect=1&lq=1). @tpain try adding a `print(arg)` inside your class's init function and notice how `arg` is *empty* for your second method! Also try printing both `foo().arg` and `x.arg` at the end of both methods, they are only equal in the `+=` case. Also [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43785469/565489) for an easier example.

Comment: Awesome @Asmus, thanks! I agree, this is a duplicate of your linked question(s).