# What is the difference between a+=1 and a=+1..?

Tags: python

how to understand difference between `a+=1` and `a=+1` in Python?

it seems that they're different. when I debug them in Python IDLE both were having different output.

Comment: `(plus)1` is just `1` (positive 1), so `a=+1` is just `a=1`. `(plus)` should be `+`, but stackoverflow won't let me start my comment off with `+1` :(

Comment: One is `a += 1`, augmented assignment equivalent to `a = a + 1`, the other is `a = +1`, assignment and a unary plus equivalent to `a = 1`. Unless a was zero they'll be different

Comment: When you ask about some behavior that is unexpected, please provide the necessary code and input data to reproduce the exact isssue, and what you expected to happen instead. `a += 1` _alone_ will give a `NameError`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider this:

```
a = 1

a = +1   # Assign Var a to value -> +1
a = +1   # Assign Var a to value -> +1
a = +1   # Assign Var a to value -> +1

a += 1
a += 1
a += 1
print(a)  # -> 4
```

As you can see this `a = +1` it's a [variable assignment](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_variables.asp) (as corrected by @adir abargil) , but `a += 1` does add 1 to var `a`.

This is the same as a = a+1, and is called: **Assignment operator**

---

### Other Stack Overflow Answers

- [a += b not the same as a = a + b [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4841451/13903942)
- [Why does += behave unexpectedly on lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347265/why-does-behave-unexpectedly-on-lists)

### Documentations

- [w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_assignment_operators.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_assignment_operators.asp)
- [programiz.com/python-programming/operators](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/operators)

Comment: Yes you right, it define the variable again, I wanted to explain that but in the rush I wrote that does nothing (for a beginner eye seems it does nothing, but is wrong) ! I edit now :)

Answer (score 4):

Of course they are different - `a+=1` sets value of `a` to `a + 1`  and
`a=+1` sets value of `a` to 1:

```
>>> a = 2
>>> a += 1
>>> a
3
>>> a =+1
>>> a
1
```

Answer (score 2):

`a+=1` is `a += 1`, where `+=` is a single operator meaning the same as `a = a + 1`.

`a=+1` is `a = + 1`, which assigns `+ 1` to the variable without using the original value of `a`

Comment: And `+1 == 1`, if that wasn't obvious

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the type of object that `a` references.

For the case that `a` is another `int`:

The `+=` is a single operator, an augmented assignment operator, that invokes `a=a.__add__(1)`, for immutables. It is equivalent to `a=a+1` and returns a new int object bound to the variable `a`.

The `=+` is parsed as two operators using the normal order of operations:

1. `+` is a unary operator working on its right-hand-side argument invoking the special function `a.__pos__()`, similar to how `-a` would negate `a` via the unary `a.__neg__()` operator.
2. `=` is the normal assignment operator

For mutables `+=` invokes `__iadd__()` for an in-place addition that should return the mutated original object.