# How can just using the += "syntactic sugar" cause an infinite loop?

Tags: python, addition, syntactic-sugar

Let `a = [-1, -2, -3]`. I want to modify the list `a` so that `a == [-1, -2, -3, 1, 2, 3]`, and I want to use `map` to achieve that.

I have the following different pieces of code I've written to do this:

1. `a = a + map(abs, a)`
2. `a = a + list(map(abs, a))`
3. `a += map(abs, a)`
4. `a += list(map(abs, a))`

Here's the results:

1. **`TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "map") to list`**
2. Works as expected: `a = [-1, -2, -3, 1, 2, 3]`
3. **Hangs indefinitely** before getting terminated with no error message (potentially ran out of memory?)
4. Works as expected: `a = [-1, -2, -3, 1, 2, 3]`

I thought that `a += b` was just syntactic sugar for `a = a + b`, but, given how (1) and (3) behave, that's clearly that's not the case.

Why does (1) give an error, while (3) seems to go into an infinite loop, despite one generally just being a syntactic sugar version of the other?

Comment: I have already closed this question as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841436/what-exactly-does-do). However, **[this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347265/why-does-behave-unexpectedly-on-lists?rq=3) also has some helpful explanations** and descriptions as to why this happens, namely because lists are mutable and `+=` operates in-place, whereas `+` tries to create a new object.

Comment: The code `a += map(abs, a)` causing an infinite loop is a very interesting example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the examples show, `a += b` is **not equivalent** to `a = a + b`, and [this answer explains why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4845327/5049813).

Under the hood, `a += b` calls `__iadd__`, which, when `a` is a list, iterates over `b`, adding each element of `b` to `a`. However, `a = a + b` will call `__add__`, on (the 2nd) `a`, which will try to concatenate `b` to (the 2nd) `a` essentially all at once, but the method will detect that `b` is not a `list` and fail.

The `a += b` case causes an infinite loop, because `map`, when iterated over, only computes and yields one element at a time. Thus, it will yield back the first number, `abs(-1) == 1`, which will be appended to `a` so `a == [-1, -2, -3, 1]`. Then, *after the append*,  it will be asked to yield back the second number, `abs(-2) == 2`, so `a == [-1, -2, -3, 1, 2]`. This continues until `a == [-1, -2, -3, 1, 2, 3]`, and then *still* continues (because there are now more values in `a` than just the original three values.). So `map` will return `abs(1) == 1` next, and so now `a == [-1, -2, -3, 1, 2, 3, 1]` and then on the next step, `a == [-1, -2, -3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2]`, and so on, until it runs out of memory.

**In short, `+=` calls `__iadd__` and `+` calls `__add__` and they're implemented differently.** The `__iadd__` function will run on anything that can be iterated over, but `__add__` does a type check to make sure the thing it's concatenating is a list. Thus, `+=` causes an infinite loop while `+` leads to an error.