# Ellipsis lists [...] and concatenating a list to itself

Tags: python, list, concatenation

**EDIT:** I was careless in my original examples. The behaviour occurs not when I add list `A` to itself, but rather when I add a list *containing* list `A` to `A` itself. Please see the corrected examples below.

---

I am trying to understand how ellipsis lists (those lists that appear as `[...]` and occur when you have a list references itself) works in Python 2.

In particular, I want to know why, if `A` is a `list`, `A = A + A` seems to work differently to `A += A` (and `A.append(A)`).

That is, why do you get:

```
>>> a = [1, 2]  
>>> a = a + [a]
>>> a  
[1, 2, [1, 2]]
```

vs.

```
>>> a = [1, 2]  
>>> a += [a]
>>> a
[1, 2, [...]]
```

(Note that `a.append(a)` seems to work for me just as the latter did.)

Any additional more general information regarding this ellipsis list phenomenon would also be much appreciated if it helps to clarify things.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347265/what-does-plus-equals-do-in-python

Comment: `a = [1, 2]; a+=a` will make `[1, 2, 1, 2]`, not `[1, 2, [1, 2]`. See the duplicate question.

Comment: The so-called duplicate does not discuss ellipsis lists *at all*.

Comment: I don't understand the closevotes either. The concept of pointers is important for python, and deserves to be explained.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit:** (to address the additional issues raised by your edits to the question):

`a = a + b` and `a += b` are not the same operation. The former executes `a.__add__(b)`, the latter executes `a.__iadd__(b)` ("in-place add").

The difference between the two is that the former always creates a new object (and rebinds the name `a` to that new object) while the latter modifies the object in-place (if it can, and with a list, it can).

To illustrate this, just look at the addresses of your objects:

```
>>> a = [1, 2]
>>> id(a)
34660104
>>> a = a + [a]
>>> id(a)
34657224
>>> id(a[2])
34660104
```

The "new" `a` was constructed from scratch, first taking the values from the old list `a`, then concatenating the reference to the old object to it.

Contrast this to:

```
>>> a = [1, 2]
>>> id(a)
34658632
>>> a += [a]
>>> id(a)
34658632
>>> id(a[2])
34658632
```

---

(Old answer, explaining cyclic references):

Consider this:

```
>>> a = [1, 2]; a += a
>>> a
[1, 2, 1, 2]
>>> a = [1, 2]; a.extend(a)
>>> a
[1, 2, 1, 2]
>>> a = [1, 2]; a += [a]
>>> a
[1, 2, [...]]
>>> a = [1, 2]; a.append(a)
>>> a
[1, 2, [...]]
```

So, to summarize the first part:

For lists, `a += a` is equivalent to calling `a.extend(a)` which modifies `a` in-place, adding copies of the elements found in `a` at the start of this operation.

Conversely, `a += [a]` corresponds to `a.append(a)`, both of which create a reference to the list `a` (i. e. a pointer to its address in memory) and add *that* to the list. Which constitutes a so-called "cyclic reference".

If you were to look at the internal representation of `a` at that point, it would look something like this:

```
a:    Reference to a list object at address 0xDEADBEEF
a[0]: Reference to the integer object "1"
a[1]: Reference to the integer object "2"
a[2]: Reference to the same list object at address 0xDEADBEEF
```

Old Python versions (pre-1.5.1) were not smart enough to detect that, so if you were to do a `print a`, you'd get `[1, 2, [1, 2, [1, 2, [1, 2, [1, 2, [1, 2, ...` etc. in an infinite loop. Since Python 1.5.1, the interpreter detects this, printing `[1, 2, [...]]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
In [179]: a = [1, 2]

In [180]: a+=a

In [181]: a
Out[181]: [1, 2, 1, 2]

In [182]: a.append(a)

In [183]: a
Out[183]: [1, 2, 1, 2, [...]]

In [184]: a[5]
-----------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Trace
C:\Users\Marcin\Documents\oneclickcos\oneclickc
----> 1 a[5]

IndexError: list index out of range

In [185]: a[4]
Out[185]: [1, 2, 1, 2, [...]]

In [186]: a[3]
Out[186]: 2

In [187]: a[4]
Out[187]: [1, 2, 1, 2, [...]]

In [188]: a
Out[188]: [1, 2, 1, 2, [...]]

In [189]: a[4][3]
Out[189]: 2

In [190]: a[4][4]
Out[190]: [1, 2, 1, 2, [...]]

In [191]: a[4][5]
-----------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Trace
C:\Users\Marcin\Documents\oneclickcos\oneclickc
----> 1 a[4][5]

IndexError: list index out of range

In [192]: a[4][4]
Out[192]: [1, 2, 1, 2, [...]]

In [193]: a = [1, 2]

In [194]: a+=a

In [195]: a
Out[195]: [1, 2, 1, 2]

In [196]: a
Out[196]: [1, 2, 1, 2]

In [197]: a
Out[197]: [1, 2, 1, 2]

In [198]: a.append(a)

In [200]: a
Out[200]: [1, 2, 1, 2, [...]]

In [201]: a.append(a)

In [202]: a
Out[202]: [1, 2, 1, 2, [...], [...]]

In [203]: a[4]
Out[203]: [1, 2, 1, 2, [...], [...]]

In [204]: a[5]
Out[204]: [1, 2, 1, 2, [...], [...]]

In [205]: id(a)
Out[205]: 64692680L

In [206]: id(a[5])
Out[206]: 64692680L

In [207]: id(a[4])
Out[207]: 64692680L

In [208]: id(a) == id(a[4]) and id(a[4]) == id(a[5])
Out[208]: True
```

Notice first of all that `+=` does not create an ellipsis list.

Secondly, it can be seen that the ellipsis-list indicates that accesing that slot will return *the exact same list* - the ellipsis-list represents a pointer to the outer list (or, almost certainly *an* outer list if there is more than one level of nesting).

Answer (score 0):

This is because `a = a + a` corresponds to `a.extend(a)` which ["Extend the list by appending all the items in the given list"](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists). Another way to look at it is that the `+` operator results in ["the concatenation of s and t"](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange).

This is in contrast to `a += a` which corresponds to `a.append(a)` which ["adds an item at the end of the list"](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

Hope that clarifies things.