# l1 is a list, l2 = l1; why doesn't "l2 = l2 + [item]" affect l1 while "l2 += [item]" does?

Tags: python, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does plus equals (+=) do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347265/what-does-plus-equals-do-in-python)

I noticed a strange problem:

```
    l1 = ['1', '2', '3']
    l2 = l1

    item = l2.pop(0)
    # the pop operation will effect l1
    print l1

    l2 = l2 + [item]
    # why "l2 = l2 + [item]" does't effect l1 while "l2 += [item]" does.
    print l2
    print l1
```

The output is:

```
['2', '3']
['2', '3', '1']
['2', '3']
```

But if i change `l2 = l2 + [item]` into `l2 += [item]`, the output will be:

```
['2', '3']
['2', '3', '1']
['2', '3', '1']
```

Comment: How is it a problem? It's just the way it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`+` and `+=` are different operators woth different internal meaning as described [here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types).

`l2 = l1 + x` calls `l2 = l1.__add__(x)`, if that doesn't work it calls `x.__radd__(l1)`. Both should return a new object forming the result of the operation, independent from the old one, thus not affecting `l1`.

`l2 += x` calls `l2 = l2.__iadd__(x)` ("augmented assignment"), and only if this doesn't work, falls back to `l2 = l2 + x` as described above.

With numbers, both are the same, because they are immutable and thus cannot be modified with `+=`, while on lists, `+` returns a new object while `+=` modifies the left hand side one.

As the object behind `l2` is modified and `l1` refers the same object, you notice the change on `l1` as well.

Answer (score 1):

After you assign `l2 = l1`, `l2` is the same as `l1`.
The following `pop` operation affects both `l1` and `l2` as they are the same.

`l2 = l2 + [item]` creates a new list. So `l2` is now a different object.

`l2 += [item]` modifies `l2` inplace. So `l2` points to the same thing as `l1`.

Interactive visualization of your code execution:

- [First](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=l1+%3D+%5B%271%27,+%272%27,+%273%27%5D%0Al2+%3D+l1%0A%0Aitem+%3D+l2.pop%280%29%0A%0Al2+%3D+l2+%2B+%5Bitem%5D&mode=display&cumulative=false&py=2&curInstr=0_)
- [Second](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=l1+%3D+%5B%271%27,+%272%27,+%273%27%5D%0Al2+%3D+l1%0A%0Aitem+%3D+l2.pop%280%29%0A%0Al2+%2B%3D+%5Bitem%5D&mode=display&cumulative=false&py=2&curInstr=0)

Some relevant links:

- [Names in Python](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#python-has-names).
- [More on lists](http://henry.precheur.org/python/copy_list)

Comment: Note that the OP didn't ask for an explanation. He said he "noticed a problem"...

Comment: @phant0m Right. Because he didn't understand how things work. So explaining them is the thing to do.

Comment: @glglgl That's a weird way to put you don't understand something... but still, he did observe what the differences are, and the accepted answer doesn't explain any more than that. Yours on the other hand actually provides more detail.

Comment: @phant0m This question seems to be a candidate for closing! So I just answered for the question to not be left without the answer (I sometimes find better answers to my own problems in the closed questions here)

Comment: @phant0m If I don't realize I didn't understand something right I might consider things a problem which really aren't...