# finding the longest substring of letters in alphabetical order in a given string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, substring

When executing my code for the given task, I keep getting the longest string plus the next letter in the iteration. For example, if I use

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'
```

I will get `"beggha"` as the longest string, when the answer is supposed to be `"beggh"`. This same bug occurs for all strings of random letters I tried.

I have figured out that the extra letter gets added on after the "result += letters" statement, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Here is my code:

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'
result = []
final = []
for letters in s:
    result += letters
    if result == sorted(result) and len(result) >= len(final):
        final=result
    elif result != sorted(result): 
        result = [result[len(result)-1]]
print "".join(final)
```

Comment: I really don't know why this question deserved downvotes. While it is obviously homework, the OP stated a clear question and put effort into solving it on his own. Does not knowing about the subtleties of augmented assignment operators deserve downvotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `result` and `final` point to the same list.
You are probably thinking that `+=` will create a new list when you issue `result += letters`, but it won't:

```
>>> x = [1,2]
>>> y = x
>>> x += [3]
>>> x
[1, 2, 3]
>>> y
[1, 2, 3]
>>> x is y
True
```

However, when you use `x = x + [3]`:

```
>>> x = [1,2]
>>> y = x
>>> x = x + [3]
>>> x
[1, 2, 3]
>>> y
[1, 2]
>>> x is y
False
```

For an explanation of this behavior, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347265/why-does-behave-unexpectedly-on-lists) question. This is what's happening in your `for` loop (edit: of your original code) when `letters` is the last `a` character in your string:

1. at the beginning, `final` and `result` both point to `['b', 'e', 'g', 'g', 'h']`.
2. after `result += 'a'` `final` and `result` both point to `['b', 'e', 'g', 'g', 'h', 'a']`.
3. now the `elif` block is entered and result will point to a new list `['a']`, while `final` still points to `['b', 'e', 'g', 'g', 'h', 'a']`.
4. `final` will never be updated again after this

Hence, your original code (before you edited it) can be fixed by changing

`result += letters`

to

`result = result + [letters]`:

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'
result = []
final = []
for letters in s:
    result = result + [letters]        
    if result == sorted(result) and len(result) >= len(final):
        final=result            
    elif result != sorted(result):
        result = [result[len(result)-1]]        

print(final)
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got a couple items to address. The first is that when you use...

```
final = result
```

This is not just assigning the values in result to final. It points the variable 'final' to the memory address containing the list that 'result' is also pointing to. So then if result is changed, so is final. To assign the *values* in result, use...

```
final = result[:]
```

which will give you the values of a slice of the list from beginning to end. Or you can use...

```
final = list(result)
```

After that change, you'll need to remove the length comparison in your elif statement.

Edited code:

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'

result = []
final = []

for letters in s:
    result += letters
    if result == sorted(result) and len(result) >= len(final):
        final = list(result)
    elif result != sorted(result):
        result = [result[len(result)-1]]
print "".join(final)
```