# understanding output of class in python

Tags: python, class, oop, object

I am a beginner in programming and have started working on Python.I am running following code.Please explain me the sequence flow for the output

```
class Employee:
   empCount = 0

   def __init__(self, name, salary):
      self.name = name
      self.salary = salary
      self.empCount += 1

   def displayEmployee(self):
      print "Name : ", self.name,  ", Salary: ", self.salary

emp1 = Employee("ABC", 2000)
emp2 = Employee("DEF", 5000)

print "Total Emp   : %d" % Employee.empCount
print "Total Emp1 : %d" % emp1.empCount
print "Total Emp2: %d" % emp2.empCount
```

and I get following output:

```
Total Emp  : 0
Total Emp1 : 1
Total Emp2: 1
```

Comment: What *precisely* don't you understand? The one thing that might trip you up is that `self.empCount += 1` is assigning to an *instance attribute*, using and then shadowing the *class attribute* of the same name, which is why the last line doesn't show `2`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using augmented assignment. For an immutable type like an integer, you are essentially doing *the same thing* as this:

```
  self.empCount = self.empCount + 1
```

The `self.empCount` retrieves either an instance attribute (if it exists) or a class attribute. Because there is no such instance attribute, it is the class attribute (set to `0`) that is retrieved and `1` is assigned to `self.empCount`. Assignment to an instance attribute *always* sets an instance attribute, never the class attribute. Each of your instances thus ends up with `self.empCount` set to `1` and the class attribute never changes.

Note that even if `empCount` was a *mutable* type, such as a list, the assignment would give you an instance attribute *anyway*, even if the augmented assignment *also* mutated the class attribute. See [Why does += behave unexpectedly on lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347265/why-does-behave-unexpectedly-on-lists) Augmented assignment on non-existing instance attributes is rarely a good idea., because the augmented assignment does this:

```
self.empCount = self.empCount.__iadd__(1)
```

Note the explicit assignment to the `self.empCount` attribute.

If you wanted to increment the *class* attribute, you need to do so explicitly:

```
Employee.empCount += 1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class Employee:
   empCount = 0
```

by here, Total Emp, which just show Employee.empCount remains 0.

```
 def __init__(self, name, salary):
      self.name = name
      self.salary = salary
      self.empCount += 1
```

this inherits and defines the Employee, and adds self.empcount. Which as a result, adds 1 to empCount.

```
emp1 = Employee("ABC", 2000)
emp2 = Employee("DEF", 5000)
```

emp1 and emp2 is separate object and affected by **init** individually, which makes empCount 1.

Comment: This doesn't really *explain why*. Do you know the difference between instance and class attributes?

Comment: Isn't this assignment to an instance attribute?

Comment: So why does it not alter the class attribute? The OP used augmented assignment, after all. Why isn't the output `2`, `1`, `2`?