# How is list += implemented in Python?

Tags: python

What is its time and space complexity?

I haven't been able to find an authoritative answer elsewhere on the web.

Also, not sure why, but StackOverflow won't let me post this question until I write more text in this box.

Comment: I'm left wondering, where's your question? By simply saying _"What is its time and space complexity?"_ no one will figure it out for you, I thought I'm reading physics here. You should add examples and explain what you're looking for.

Comment: @direprobs: Time and space complexity are standard computer programming terms; the question's meaning is evident without examples or further explanation.

Comment: @direprobs: both terms have CS meaning too, they are not just physics terms.

Comment: There are answers here on SO that [detail how `+=` works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347265/why-does-behave-unexpectedly-on-lists), and from there found that [this is already documented on the Python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If the form is trying to stop you posting short, unspecific questions, then maybe you need to rethink your question, not just type filler text. Ingest [ask] to have a better experience in future.

Comment: This kind of thing is a lot harder to find than you might expect for a newbie. The wiki page doesn't actually list `+=` or space complexity, and the resources that come up for a search for `Python list += complexity` don't make it apparent that `+=` and `extend` are mostly equivalent. It's harder than you'd expect to get the filter to accept your questions, too, especially since the feedback is pretty bad. I actually had to make my first question *worse* to get the site to take it when I was starting out.

Answer (score 4):

`l += other_thing` is mostly equivalent to

```
l.extend(other_thing)
```

or

```
for thing in other_thing:
    l.append(thing)
```

Under the hood, the list stores an array of pointers to its elements, usually with extra space at the end to accommodate future elements. Appending elements consists of a pointer copy and a reference count update if the list has room; if the list is out of room, the array is copied into a multiplicatively larger array first.

The average-case and amortized time complexity of the `+=` operation is `O(len(other_thing))`; the worst-case time complexity is `O(len(l) + len(other_thing))`. The size of the individual elements doesn't matter. The operation could require `O(len(l) + len(other_thing))` space for a resize, although most of the space it uses is part of `l`.

Answer (score 3):

the source code for python is freely available on github so you can always go look at it

```
static PyObject *
list_inplace_concat(PyListObject *self, PyObject *other)
{
    PyObject *result;

    result = listextend(self, other);
    if (result == NULL)
        return result;
    Py_DECREF(result);
    Py_INCREF(self);
    return (PyObject *)self;
}
```

as you can see it just calls listextend, which you can see the complexity of at https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity