# Passing Lists to function in Python

Tags: python

I don't understand why these functions give different results; I thought that `s+=` and `s=s+` were equivalent:

```
def foo(s): 
     s += ['hi']

def foo2(s):
     s = s + ['hi']
```

But the first modifies the list `s` and the second does not. Could someone help me clarifying this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2347265/3001761

Comment: *"I thought that s+= and s=s+ were equivalent"* they sometimes are (with `int`s for example) but not always. Usually with mutable objects, `+=` mutates the object in place, but `x = x + y` creates a new object with `x + y` and then assigns it to the variable `x`. Usually. Each class gets to decide how it wants to work

Comment: it is not the same. first is like `s.extends(["hi"])` a second is like `b = s + ["hi"] ; s = b`

Answer (score 3):

`x+= y` is same as `x = x + y` only for immutable types. For mutable types, the option exists to alter the object in-place. So for lists, `+=` is the same as `list.extend()` followed by a re-bind of the name.

Read: [Augmented Assignment Statements](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements) and [Why does += behave unexpectedly on lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347265/why-does-behave-unexpectedly-on-lists) for more information.

Answer (score -1):

Use list.append because if you say s = s +['hi'] then s just point to another object, but if you use .append() then the same list is being changed