# Appending a range to a list

Tags: python, list, python-2.x

I have some basic code that I'm not grasping the behaviour of:

```
L = [ 'a', 'bb', 'ccc' ]

L.append(range(2))
print len(L)

print len(L + range(1))

print len(L)
```

The output of which is

```
4
5
4
```

This is confusing to me, as my thought process is that the length of the initial list is 3, and appending `range(2)` to the end brings it to length of 5. Therefore I'd expect the output to be `5 6 5`. I'm sure it's a simple quirk, but I'm a bit lost and having a hell of a time trying to find an answer online. Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: `.append(range(2))` adds **exactly one element** to the list, *always*. So you've added `[0, 1]` to that list.

Comment: `append` is not the same as `extend`. Try `print(L)` and you'll understand.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You appended a single list object. You did not add the elements *from* the list that `range` produces to `L`. A nested list object adds just one more element:

```
>>> L = ['a', 'bb', 'ccc']
>>> L.append(range(2))
>>> L
['a', 'bb', 'ccc', [0, 1]]
```

Note the `[0, 1]`, the output of the `range()` function.

You are looking for `list.extend()` instead:

```
>>> L = ['a', 'bb', 'ccc']
>>> L.extend(range(2))
>>> L
['a', 'bb', 'ccc', 0, 1]
>>> len(L)
5
```

As an alternative to `list.extend()`, in most circumstances you can use `+=` augmented assignment too (but take into account the updated `L` list is assigned back to `L`, which can [lead to surprises when `L` was a class attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347265/why-does-behave-unexpectedly-on-lists)):

```
>>> L = ['a', 'bb', 'ccc']
>>> L += range(2)
>>> L
['a', 'bb', 'ccc', 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Insert A Range of item or to List anywhere

```
 g=[1,2,3,4,7,8]        
    z=[5,6]
    def insertRange(start,YourList,anotherlist):
        if isinstance(YourList,list) and isinstance(anotherlist,list) :
            YourlistPart1=YourList[0:start]
            YourlistPart2=YourList[start:]
            YourlistPart1.extend(anotherlist)
            YourlistPart1.extend(YourlistPart2)
            print(YourlistPart1)
    
    insertRange(4,g,z)
```

You can't insert range in a specific location in python but you can work around by function using extend  you can split your list extend first part and then merge the 2 lists again  start= doesn't start from 0 if you wish to start insert from index 3 which = 4 in the example you start with 3

summary

start from 1 adds the list after the index 0 and shift the other elements

start from 4 adds the list after the index 3 and shift the other elements

start from 5 adds the list after the index 4