# How to pass a range as a list element to a list in python?

Tags: python, list, range, openpyxl

I want to pass a range of numbers to a list.
Here I set the variable rowsList which contain a list of index numbers.

```
rowsList = [range(13),17,23]
for index in rowsList:
    ws.insert_rows(index,1)
```

Obviously it raises: TypeError: 'range' object cannot be interpreted as an integer. What little change could I do to make this work ?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Can you show us what you're expecting to happen? What is `ws`?

Comment: What are you expecting from `rowsList`?

Comment: See the answer to [Appending a range to a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42437608/appending-a-range-to-a-list).

Comment: @brunns My question is solved but just so you know, `ws` is the name I gave to my worksheet (Openpyxl library, see tags). I didn't find relevant to mention it :-)

Comment: You should note that the in order which rows are inserted matters as each insertion moves all the rows below. As it stands inserting `range(13)` makes little sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *** (Extended Iterable Unpacking) operator**
>
> Proposes a change to iterable unpacking syntax, allowing to specify a "catch-all" name which will be assigned a list of all items not
>   assigned to a "regular" name.

```
rowsList = [*range(13),17,23]
print (rowsList)
```

output :

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 17, 23]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want `[17, 23, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]`

```
rowsList = [17, 23]
rowsList.extend(range(13))
```

Assuming you want `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 17, 23]`

```
rowsList = [17, 23]
tmpList = []
tmpList.extend(range(13))
rowsList[:0] = tmpList
```