# use .append more than once?

Tags: python, list, append

Is there a quicker way to write .append more than once?
Like:

```
    combo.append(x) * 2
```

Instead of:

```
    combo.append(x)
    combo.append(x)
```

I know you cant multiply it by 2, so I'm wondering if there is a faster way?

Comment: Thanks that was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: You can select just *one* of the answers, not both. :-) Pick the one that *you* feel helped you the most. Not picking any is a valid choice too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try something like `combo.extend([x]*t)` to append `t` copies of x.

Answer (score 1):

You can *extend* instead of append:

```
combo.extend([x] * 2)
```

If `combo` is a local or a global, you can also use `+=` to extend a list:

```
combo += [x] * 2
```

If `combo` is an class attribute, just be careful if you are referencing it on an instance, see [Why does += behave unexpectedly on lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347265/why-does-behave-unexpectedly-on-lists)