# python: what does the comma do in += s,?

Tags: python

I am doing a problem, the input is strings:

```
["abc","bcd","acef","xyz","az","ba","a","z"]
```

The code is listed below.

```
def groupStrings(self, strings):
    groups = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for s in strings:
        tmp=[0]*len(s)
        for i in range(len(s)):
            tmp[i]=(ord(s[i])-ord(s[0]))%26
            tmptuple=tuple(tmp)

        groups[tmptuple] += s,
    return groups.values()
```

So in **`groups[tmptuple]+=s,`**

if I remove the comma ','
I get

```
[["a","b","c","b","c","d","x","y","z"],["a","c","e","f"],["a","z"],["a","z","b","a"]]
```

instead of

```
[["abc","bcd","xyz"],["acef"],["a","z"],["az","ba"]]
```

The groups just does not add the whole string s, can anyone explain why does the comma make it different and why I could not do it without the comma?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2347265/4909087

Answer (score 8):

The trailing comma makes a `tuple`, with a single element, `s`. Python doesn't require parentheses to make a `tuple` unless there is ambiguity (e.g. with function call parens); aside from the empty `tuple` (`()`), you can usually make `tuple`s with just commas, no parentheses at all. In this case, a single trailing comma, `s,`, is equivalent to `(s,)`.

Since `groups` has `list` values, this means that doing `+= s,` is equivalent to `.append(s)` (technically, it's closer to `.extend((s,))`, but the end result is the same). Someone is probably trying to save a few keystrokes.

If you omitted the comma, it would be doing `list += str`, interpreting the `str` as a sequence of characters and extending the list with each of the resulting len 1 strings, as you observed.