# Concatenation of a string to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, concatenation

I ran the following code in Jupyter Notebook:

```
list_1 = []
list_1 += "cat"
print(list_1)
```

and got the following output:

```
['c', 'a', 't']
```

but when i ran this:

```
list_1 = []
list_1 = list_1 + "cat"
print(list_1)
```

it gave the following error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

I failed to understand this as in both the methods, a string is being added to a list.

Is it something about the '+=' notation or something related to the concatenation  of lists and strings that's causing the bug?

Comment: There is an [excellent answer on the difference between + and +=](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347265/why-does-behave-unexpectedly-on-lists). Beside that, note that Python tries to interpret “cat” as a list, which defaults to a list of the individual characters.

Comment: I did check that answer. The problem I was interested in was the concatenation of a string to a list but that answer only addresses how the `+=` notation affects the concatenation of two lists. As you cleared it out that Python treats "cat" as a list of characters, I am able to completely understand the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`list_1 += "cat"` is calling `list_1.__iadd__` which uses `list_1.extend("cat")` internally and appends every character from the iterable `"cat"` to the list one by one.

`list_1 + "cat"` attempts to call `list_1.__add__` and this method fails as you noticed because it expects two lists.