# a = []; a += 'abc' versus a = a+'abc'

Tags: python, string, list, syntax

I understand that you cannot concatenate a list and a string. So it makes sense that `a=a+'abc'` throws an exception "TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list".

But why does `a+='abc'` result in `a == ['a','b','c']`?

I thought `a = a+b` and `a+=b` should always give the same result.

Comment: `+=` is like calling `a.extend()`

Comment: see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347265/why-does-behave-unexpectedly-on-lists#comment78372641_2347423 and the next answer

Comment: In *general*, a = a+b and a+=b are not equivalent

Comment: `+=` takes another *iterable* and adds all its items to the list. `+` concatenates *two lists*.