# Creating a list of all words that are both in a given string and in a given dictionary

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

I'm working with a string and a dictionary in Python, trying to loop through the string in order to create a list of the words which appear both in the string and amongst the keys of the dictionary. What I have currently is:

```
## dictionary will be called "dict" below
sentence = "is this is even really a sentence"
wordsinboth = []
for w in sentence.split():
    if w in dict:
        wordsinboth += w
```

Instead of returning a list of words split by whitespace, however, this code returns a list of every character in the sentence. 
The same thing occurs even when I attempt to create a list of split words before looping, as seen below:

```
sentence = "is this is even really a sentence"
wordsinboth = []
sent = sentence.split()
for w in sent:
    if w in dict:
        wordsinboth += w
```

I guess I'm not able to specify "if w in dict" and still split by whitespace? Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `append` instead of `+=`:

```
sentence = "is this is even really a sentence"
wordsinboth = []
for w in sentence.split():
    if w in dict:
        wordsinboth.append(w)
```

The `+=` operator doesn't work as you'd expect:

```
a = [] 
myString = "hello"
a.append(myString)

print(a) # ['hello']

b = [] 
b += myString

print(b) # ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

If you're interested on why this happens, the following questions are a good read:

- [Why does += behave unexpectedly on lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347265/why-does-behave-unexpectedly-on-lists)
- [What is the difference between Python's list methods append and extend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/what-is-the-difference-between-pythons-list-methods-append-and-extend)

---

Also, note that using list comprehensions might result in a more elegant solution to your problem:

```
wordsinboth = [word for word in sentence.split() if word in dict]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `+=` on a list, but you must add a list to it, not a value, otherwise the value gets converted to a list before being added. In your case, the `w` strings are being converted to a list of all the characters in them (e.g. `'if'` => `['i', 'f']`). To work around that, make the value into a list by adding `[]` around it:

```
for w in sentence.split():
    if w in dict:
        wordsinboth += [w]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehensions it's more shortest and elegant way for your case:

```
wordsinboth = [word for word in sentence.split() if w in dict]
```

Problem in your cycle that you have to use `append` for adding new item to `wordsinboth` instead of `+` operator, also please keep in mind that it can create duplicates, if you need uniq items you can wrap your result to `set` which gives you uniq words.

Like this:

```
wordsinboth = {word for word in sentence.split() if w in dict}
```