# What is the difference between x += [0] and x = x + [0]?

Tags: python, list

I found that there is a difference between extending a list with x += [0] and x = x + [0].

```
x = [1]
y = x
x += [0]
print(x, y)
```

The above prints [1,0] [1,0]. Compared to below:

```
x = [1]
y = x
x = x + [0]
print(x, y)
```

which prints [1, 0] [1].
Why does this happen?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does += behave unexpectedly on lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347265/why-does-behave-unexpectedly-on-lists)

Comment: `list.__iadd__` updates `x` in-place; `list.__add__` does not.