# extend vs += for immutable sequence in python

Tags: python, immutability, extend

The python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) imply that `s.extend(t)` and `s += t` are equivalent for some mutable sequence `s` and iterable `t`.  I'm surprised to find that they are not equivalent for an immutable sequence.  Can someone shed some light on why extend raises an error

```
>>> s = (1, 2)
>>> s.extend((3,))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'extend'
```

but += does not

```
>>> s = (1, 2)
>>> s += (3,)
>>> s
(1, 2, 3)
```

Is there a practical reason why `extend` can't create a new tuple the way `+=` does?

Comment: I think you misunderstood the error. Tuple's do not have a method `extend`. That is why you can't call it, not because it can't create a new tuple, but because that is not a method for tuple's.

Comment: Tuple isn't a *mutable* type, so none of the stuff in the documentation about mutable sequence types applies. So then the answer lies in what `+=` falls back to when the class doesn't implement `__iadd__`…

Comment: @Chrispresso I get that, but if += is equivalent to extend for mutable objects, and immutable objects support +=, why don't they also support extend?  It appears extend is intentionally undefined for tuples.  If there is a good reason not to define it, why should += be allowed?

Comment: @deceze do you know where I can find what += falls back to for tuples?

Comment: Read the duplicates…? And to answer your question from above: `.extend` on an immutable type would be somewhere between very misleading and nonsensical.

Comment: @deceze Thanks, I have read the duplicates (and a lot more besides).  What helped me the most was the top answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347265/why-does-behave-unexpectedly-on-lists?noredirect=1&lq=1) linked in a comment from one of the marked duplicates.