# Why list can not be concatenated with str using '+' operator in python?

Tags: python, list, concatenation

I want to make sense of difference between `list +='a'` and `list=list+'a'`
For example, if I do this:

```
li=[]
for i in 'string':
    li+=i
```

I get no error but if I use the second option which by convention should be the same but gives error

```
li=[]
for i in 'string':
    li=li+i
```

> TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Correct way to do this, would be something like this:

```
li=[]
for i in 'string':
    li=li+[i]
```

I want to know how `+=` operator is working? How it is able to get string inside the list, is it converting string to list?

Comment: The return type of `+=` is unambiguous: it's the type of the left operand. The return type of `+` is unclear. Does the programmer expect `list + str` to return a list, or a string?

Comment: [Why does += behave unexpectedly on lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347265/why-does-behave-unexpectedly-on-lists)

Comment: @khelwood `list` should be returned

Comment: `+=` is equivalent  to `list.extend` which accepts any iterable (not only lists)

Comment: Anyways, you can use `li+=[i]`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does += behave unexpectedly on lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347265/why-does-behave-unexpectedly-on-lists)

Comment: @M_S_N Yeah, I understand that's what *you* want in this use case. That doesn't hold for every developer in every possible use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know how += operator is working?

the in-place assignment `+=` operator works in 2 ways (from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/operator.html#in-place-operators)):

**1)For immutable objects**

> For immutable targets such as strings, numbers, and tuples, the
>   updated value is computed, but not assigned back to the input variable

this means that you will create a new object each time `+=` is used (if your object is immutable)

**2)For mutable objects**

> For mutable targets such as lists and dictionaries, the in-place
>   method will perform the update, so no subsequent assignment is
>   necessary

this means that you will not create a new object each time `+=` is used (if your object is mutable)

---

In your example, to use `li+=i` you have to make sure that `i` is a list, otherwise will not work

Here:

```
li = []
for i in 'string':
    li = li + [i]
```

you are concatenating 2 lists but each time you are creating a new list `li`, you can check by using the built-in funtion [id](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id):

```
li=[]
for i in '1':
    print(id(li))
    li=li+[i]
    print(id(li))
```

output:

```
140661631713104
140661644452240
```

you could use the in-place assignment `+=` operator like this:

```
li=[]
for i in '1':
    print(id(li))
    li += [i]
    print(id(li))
```

output:

```
140661641698592
140661641698592
```

as you can see the elements are appended to the `li` list without creating a new `li` list which is more efficient, this works identically like [list.extend](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

to add another element to your list, not using a list, you can use `list.append`

Comment: your answer makes a lot sense, but still a very strange design choice,  especially coming from another language where something like this `a+=a` would be equivalent to `a= a+a`

Answer (score 1):

Python docs says:

> To see why this happens, you need to know that (a) if an object implements an **__iadd__ magic method, it gets called when the +=** augmented assignment is executed, and its return value is what gets used in the assignment statement; and (b) **for lists, __iadd__ is equivalent to calling extend** on the list and returning the list. That’s why we say that for lists, **+= is a “shorthand” for list.extend**.

Since list.extend expects an iterator and a string is iterable, `+=` works in your given example. That means, you don't even need the for-loop as list.extend will iterate through the string and add the elements to the list.
`li=[]
li += "string"`

Output: `['s', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g']`

List can only concatenate (`+`) list.

Source:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types
https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#faq-augmented-assignment-tuple-error