# mutable list operand in python

Tags: python

Here is the 1st code.

```
lst=11*[[]]

print(lst)
word="Mia"
value=0
for i in word:
    value+=ord(i)
n=value%11 #Loaction number
lst[4]+=[word]
print(lst)
```

This output will  be this `[['Mia'], ['Mia'], ['Mia'], ['Mia'], ['Mia'], ['Mia'], ['Mia'], ['Mia'], ['Mia'], ['Mia'], ['Mia']]`

The 2nd one.

```
lst=11*[[]]

print(lst)
word="Mia"
value=0
for i in word:
    value+=ord(i)
n=value%11 #Loaction number
lst[4]=lst[4]+[word]
print(lst)
```

This will produce this result. `[[], [], [], [], ['Mia'], [], [], [], [], [], []]`

What's the difference between `lst[4]=lst[4]+[word]` and `lst[4]+=[word]`?

I originally assume the abbreviation of `lst[4]=lst[4]+[word]` is `lst[4]+=[word]`.

But they're apparently not.

Comment: You have value += ord(i) but you never defined ord. I think you have made a typo in the code that is causing this

Comment: @TheGrandJ, The ord() function in Python accepts a string of length 1 as an argument and returns the unicode code point representation of the passed argument.

Comment: My mistake. Thanks for correcting me

Comment: @kile, are you sure the first set of code gives you empty list and not ['mia'] 11 times?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347265/why-does-behave-unexpectedly-on-lists#:~:text=It%20takes%20all%20the%20elements,create%20a%20new%20list%20object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does += behave unexpectedly on lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347265/why-does-behave-unexpectedly-on-lists)

Comment: @JoeFerndz Sorry for the problematic result. I'll correct it now

Comment: the += operator on list works as extend. Thats why you get `'mia'` added to every element. See the link I posted. It should help.