# Why does using "+=" to append to a List[str] result in an unexpected newline character, while "c = c + a" results in c being empty?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working on this problem on LeetCode:

https://leetcode.com/problems/read-n-characters-given-read4/

The question reads:

> Given a file and assume that you can only read the file using a given
> method read4, implement a method to read n characters.
>
> **Method read4:**
>
> The API read4 reads 4 consecutive characters from the file, then
> writes those characters into the buffer array buf4.
>
> The return value is the number of actual characters read.
>
> Note that read4() has its own file pointer, much like FILE *fp in C.
>
> Definition of read4:
>
> ```
> Parameter:  char[] buf4
> Returns:    int
> ```
>
> Note: buf4[] is destination not source, the results from read4 will be
> copied to buf4[]
>
> ...
>
> **Method read:**
>
> By using the read4 method, implement the method read that reads n
> characters from the file and store it in the buffer array buf.
> Consider that you cannot manipulate the file directly.
>
> The return value is the number of actual characters read.
>
> Definition of read:
>
> ```
> Parameters:   char[] buf, int n
> Returns:  int
> ```
>
> Note: buf[] is destination not source, you will need to write the
> results to buf[]

I put together the following simple solution:

```
"""
The read4 API is already defined for you.

    @param buf4, a list of characters
    @return an integer
    def read4(buf4):

# Below is an example of how the read4 API can be called.
file = File("abcdefghijk") # File is "abcdefghijk", initially file pointer (fp) points to 'a'
buf4 = [' '] * 4 # Create buffer with enough space to store characters
read4(buf4) # read4 returns 4. Now buf = ['a','b','c','d'], fp points to 'e'
read4(buf4) # read4 returns 4. Now buf = ['e','f','g','h'], fp points to 'i'
read4(buf4) # read4 returns 3. Now buf = ['i','j','k',...], fp points to end of file
"""

class Solution:
    def read(self, buf, n):
        """
        :type buf: Destination buffer (List[str])
        :type n: Number of characters to read (int)
        :rtype: The number of actual characters read (int)
        """
        buf4 = ['']*4
        c = 1
        
        while n > 0 and c > 0:
            c = read4(buf4)
            if c:
                if n >= c:
                    buf += buf4
                elif n < c:
                    buf += buf4[:n]
            
            n -= c
        
        return len(buf)
```

When I use "+=" to add the contents of buf4 to buf I get a newline character in my output, as in the following example:

> "
> abc"

If I instead write `buf = buf + buf4`, I get just the newline character, like so:

> "
> "

Does anyone know what might be going on here? I know I could solve this problem by using for loops instead. I'm just curious to know what's going on.

I found this article that explains that "+=" and "c = c + b" use different special methods:

[Why does += behave unexpectedly on lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347265/why-does-behave-unexpectedly-on-lists)

However I don't think this explains the unexpected newline character. Does anyone know where this newline character is coming from?

Comment: Is there a difference in the length of the list for the two cases?

Comment: If by the "two cases" you're referring to the "+=" and "= +" approaches, then yes. They were both run using the same test case

Comment: Unclear where/how you are printing anything, but `repr(buf)` should show you newline characters, but using `+=` (or `.append()`) on a list doesn't add a newline character... If you are reading from a file, then files can have newlines, of course,

Comment: I'll try repr() to try and debug it, thanks. I don't think the test cases contain newlines based on the input they show on LC, but I could be wrong.