# Variable inconsistency in Python?

Tags: python

I've run into a strange inconsistency. This is a simplified version of the problem:

```
func1={
    'flist':[12,13,14],
    'fnum':10
}

dlist=func1['flist']
dnum=func1['fnum']

dlist+=[16]
dnum+=1

print(func1)
print(dnum)
```

The output is:

```
{'flist': [12, 13, 14, 16], 'fnum': 10}

11
```

Why is that the changes to the variable `dlist` *are* carried over to `flist` in `func1`, but changes in `dnum` *are not* carried over to `fnum` in `func1`?

`flist` has changed, `fnum` has not.

Comment: Lists are mutable, integers are not. `+=` on a list is like calling `.extend`, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/2347265/3001761.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with the mutability of the underlying objects. Since `func1['flist']` refers to a list, when you do `dlist=func1['flist']` you are actually getting a reference to the memory address of `func1['flist']` and then when you add another value, you are modifying the same object in memory. This is because lists are mutable objects and referred to by reference.

On the other hand when you do `dnum+=1`, what is happening in memory is that 10+1=11 is being created as a new object in memory and then `dnum` is set to point to the new memory address. This has no effect on the memory address and therefore the value of `func1['fnum']`. This is the behaviour that happens for immutable types.

Comment: _"you are getting the value itself, not a reference"_ - that's not true, you get a reference to an object in both cases.

Comment: Yeah my bad, I did a poor job explaining that. I have tried to adjust my answer to better explain it.