# Why does += work differently than its 'full form' for lists in python?

Tags: python

I was trying to write the opening blanks for a hangman game.
My code was:

```
display = []
for x in (word):
    display = display + "_"
print(display)
```

I understand that here, python thinks I'm trying to numerically add `_` to a list object, which is not possible, but why is it that `display += "_"` works fine?

Comment: Please explain what *numerically add _ to a list* means?

Comment: What do you mean by "its full form"? Will you show two versions of the code using the two forms you are refering to? And then show how the outputis different.

Comment: I think a part of my question got omitted for some reason. I meant to type that  display = display + "_" does not seem to work, whereas display += "_" works fine, although they are supposed to mean the same thing

Comment: @Sarthak Feel free to [edit] your question to fix it.

Comment: It is indeed possible in python to program the operators such that `+=` acts differently from "`+` followed by assignment".

Comment: [Why does += behave unexpectedly on lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347265/why-does-behave-unexpectedly-on-lists)

Comment: Just finished the edit, hope my doubt comes off clearer now. Apologies for the confusion!

Comment: Even though `print(display+ "_" )` does not work, you can do `print(display+["_"])`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that illustrates the behavior you are asking about. This should be something we can copy and paste and run ourselves. Your current code example has an undefined variable, so I can't run it. Also be sure to include the two different behaviors so we can see how the output differs.

Comment: I is instructive to see what happens when you do `display += "foobar"`.

Comment: Cheers @Guy, I had stumbled upon that thread while searching for an answer to my problem but thought it was somehow irrelevant to my question, I'll go through it once more.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Code-Apprentice, I think my doubt has been addressed. I'll keep your pointers in mind when I inevitably return for help with some miniscule doubts.