# Python: Can I count how many kinds of index based on certain screening criteria?

Tags: python

My goal: to know how many index satisfy criteria of **4<value<10** from a series object `count_num`.

I got the series object after `df[].value_counts()` like below (**index of a,c,e satisfy the criteria**)

*index* *value*

a       5

b       3

c       7

d       1

e       6

I tried but got error of *cannot unpack non-iterable int object*:

```
index_numb = []
for index, value in count_num:
    if 4<= value <= 10:
    index_numb += 1
```

Thank you very much for your time and comments

Comment: Try `index_numb = 0`

Comment: In the question you wrote "4 < val < 10", in the code `4 <= val <= 10` - it's not the same...

Comment: If you want to accumulate different answers, you probably need a list `my_list=[]`, using `my_list.append(new_answer)` to store the results, but if you just want to count you simply need a number, starting from zero: `my_count=0` , then `if condition_met : my_count+=1` — the answer you've accepted is not really a good answer from the point of view that I've just exposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do list comprehension to create a list of all the indicies that match and get the length of that, so something like `len([index for index in count_num if 4 < count_num[index] < 10])`

the len() part should be self-explanatory, just getting the length of whatever's passed in but the part inside is your list comprehension:

```
[index for index in count_num if 4 < count_num[index] < 10]
```

or basically create a list of all index values where count_num[index] is between 4 and 10.

That last conditional there are a few ways you can do it, either what I put, or if you didn't think that, `count_num[index] < 4 and count_num[index] < 10` or even since it's a range do something like `count-num[index] in range(4,10)`

with the way you're doing it though you'll run into several errors.

First, the reason it's failing is because doing `for index, value in count_num`, the in part uses an iterator that's returning only the keys and so it's failing.  you'd need to do `for index, value in count_num.items()`

After you fix that, your `index_numb += 1` is indented wrong so it's not considered within the scope of your if statement so you'll get an error with that.
After you fix that additionally, you're  doing `index_numb += 1` but index_numb is a list so adding 1 to it makes no sense.  You probably meant to do `index_numb = 0` then your `index_numb += 1` will increment.

Comment: Thank you very much aznanimedude. I'm sorry I do not have enough reputation to cast the vote, so I would like to at least thank you in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

code:

```
index_numb = []

index_numb += 1
```

output :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

other code:

```
index_numb = []

print(index_numb, type(index_numb))

index_numb += [1]

print(index_numb, type(index_numb))
```

output :

```
[] <class 'list'>
[1] <class 'list'>
```

see here better exolanation:

[Why does += behave unexpectedly on lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347265/why-does-behave-unexpectedly-on-lists) :

> When dealing with lists like you are, though, the += operator is a shorthand for someListObject.extend(iterableObject). See the documentation of extend().

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: Very good to learn, thank you!

Comment: Thanks for your comments on accepting answer as well, it works!

Answer (score 0):

I found a non-direct way to solve this problem. Expect some brief or direct methods to this!

`df = series.to_frame()`    #convert the series object to df

```
df['screened_output'] = df['value'].apply(lambda x: 'true' if 4<= x <= 10 else 'false')     
index_4to10 = df['screened_output'].value_counts()
```

Then I can see the number of index satisfied or not, from the value of true and false...

Comment: why didnt give us `df` and `count_num` too ? (is df panda dataframe ? ) so to test the entire code

Comment: I gave the count_num in question, and df is dataframe. Thanks a lot for your suggestion.

Comment: What type is count_num ? List of tuples , dictionary,  pandas series ? Array ?

Comment: series, as mentioned in the goal. Is the description of "series object" easy to confuse...?

Comment: To me it is, my fault I am a novice, dont know how to create/instantiate a pandas.series, how to write it down to be able to reproduce it, how to read it. I can read, lists or dicts not series, sorry

Comment: As said I did .value_counts() to a df then I got a pandas series.
I think you are very good! I'm a real novice :)

Comment: cant find them with alphanumeric index aa,b,c,... instead of 0,1,2,3 (https://www.w3schools.com/python/pandas/pandas_series.asp)

Comment: Could you explain more? I don't understand what you mean ... Or anyway, this method did work for me.

Comment: Ok i got it , that was the data frame ? So series is just 5,3,7,1,7