# Could you please explain below three codes?, why they are giving different results

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, operators

code 1

```py
list_a = []

list_a += str(1)
```

O/P:

```
['1']
```

code 2

```py
list_a = []

list_a += 1
```

O/P:

```
Type Error
```

code 3

```py
list_a = []

list_a = list_a + str(1)
```

O/P:

```
Type Error
```

I'm expecting that if `+=` operator allows concatenation between list and string, then why not int?

Also, why is `list = list + str(1)` not allowing concatenation even though `str(1)` is string type?

Comment: For lists, `+=` is essentially identical to the `extend` method, i.e. `a += b` is the same as `a.extend(b)`. You are treating it as if it behaved like the `append` method.

Comment: `+=` allows the value being added to be any kind of sequence. But `+` only allows another list.

Comment: Does the TypeError message not tell you the reason?

Comment: Also, you didn't try: `list_a += str(11)`. I think you might be surprised by the result.

Comment: Almost duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347265/why-does-behave-unexpectedly-on-lists

Answer (score 0):

+= operator is not addition or concatenation always.
When you try to add string to list with += operator, it appends each character of the string as a separate element. The different cases of += operator are as follows. Also please remember that += can't be used instead of append. Because, with +=, It appends each character as a separate element

```
#case 1

l = []
l += str(1)
print(l)  #output : ['1']

#case 2

l = []
l += '1','5','4'
print(l)  #output : ['1','5','4']

#case 3

l = []
l += '154'
print(l)  #output : ['1','5','4'] 

#Please note that each character is appended as a separate element in the above case

#case 4

l = ['1','2','3']
l += str(456)
print(l)  #output : ['1','2','3','4','5','6']

#case 5

st = 'abc'
st += '123'
print(st) #output : 'abc123'
```